# Is there a defined way to do pointer subtraction in C11?

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, c11, pointer-arithmetic

Is there a way to subtract one pointer from another in C11 and have the result be always defined?

The standard says the behavior is undefined if the result is not representable as type ptrdiff_t.

I am open to a solution relying on static assertions that are expected to pass on a reasonable implementation in a modern general purpose 32 or 64 bit environment. I would like to avoid solutions that rely on any sort of runtime checks.

If the pointed to type has size greater than 1, I can static assert size_t and ptrdiff_t to have the same number of nonpadding bits. This partial solution relies on two things I am not sure about, so any feedback on this would provide a partial answer:

1. It can be expected that ptrdiff_t has at most one fewer value bit than size_t in a reasonable implementation in a modern general purpose 32 or 64 bit environment.
2. I am correct in my understanding of the standard, in that the difference between two pointers to objects of size greater than 1 is defined, even when the same difference would be undefined if the pointers were cast to character pointers. This understanding seems inconsistent with footnote 106 in the committee draft, but it is my understanding that footnotes are not normative.

Comment: What's the purpose? You can always cast pointers to `uintptr_t` and friends...

Comment: It is cumbersome to always be doing such a cast, but more than that, that does not solve the problem. The way a pointer is represented as type uintptr_t is not defined, so subtracting the cast versions does not produce a well defined result.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You can but the value isn't meaningful. C only guarantees that the conversion to and back won't change the value.

Comment: @2501 that's why I asked about the purpose..

Comment: The purpose is just to take pointer differences in code that has to be rigorously adherent to the standard.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Arithmetic on pointers in `uintptr_t` is undefined behaviour when you cast back. Itr is also not guarateed to yield any meaningful result.

Comment: Pointer differences *per se* are not very meaningful as well. So again. What is the specific problem?

Comment: Jut check `PTRDIFF_MAX` against `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: Why would you say pointer differences are not very meaningful? I find them quite useful.

Comment: @Olaf, my requirement is to produce code that is standard compliant and that can be expected to compile on just about any reasonable implementation in a general purpose 32 or 64 bit enviroment. I didn't think I could expect PTRDIFF_MAX >= SIZE_MAX in that context. Am I mistaken? Otherwise, such a static assertion would not be allowed.

Comment: @Kyle: Your comment is not clear. That's exactly what `_Static_assert` is for.

Comment: @Olaf, I mean the static assertion wouldn't be allowed for what I am doing, because it would have a reasonable chance of causing a failure to compile. I need a solution that I can expect to compile in the type of enviroment I am talking about. For example, static asserting a 32 bit int is OK in this setting, but static asserting a 32 bit long is not OK. That is because the former is very unlikely to fail, but the latter does not share that property.

Comment: To whoever downvoted, If you are going to downvote, please give a reason. I can't see any reason to downvote this question other than not making the effort to understand what I am asking, or not agreeing with my objective (which are both inappropriate reasons to downvote).

Comment: The only solution is to limit the size of character arrays to `SIZE_MAX / 2`. That's going to require runtime checks unless the size of every character array is known at compile time. So frankly, there is no solution to this problem that meets your requirements.

Comment: @user3386109: Another solution which will work on non-obtuse two's-complement implementations where the size of an object could exceed the range of ptrdiff_t is to observe that [assuming 16-bit for simplicity of example] given `char *q = p+49152`, `q-p` will yield `-16384` but `p+(-16384)` will equal `q`.  The Standard doesn't mandate that implementations that would be unable to guarantee wrap-around behavior must either make `ptrdiff_t` big enough to handle all objects or limit the size of objects to fit `ptrdiff_t`, but it makes no effort to specify everything about useful implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### According to the Standard

You can only subtract pointers if both pointers point to the same object, which includes the "one-past-the-end" pointer.

Subtracting `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` is not necessarily meaningful, because, again, according to the standard, there is no particular way that the conversion from pointer to integer has to be defined.  In particular,

- Consider far pointers in a segmented memory model, where there may be more than one way to represent a given address (segment + offset, for example, on x86).
- Consider pointers with bits that are ignored by processor.  (For example, the Motorola 68000 processor, which has 32-bit pointers but the top 8 bits are ignored.)

So, unfortunately, there is no way to do this portably, according to the standard.

**Remember:** `size_t` is the maximum size of an object.  It is *not* the size of your address space.  It is entirely legal for `size_t` to have less range that `uintptr_t` and friends.  Same with `ptrdiff_t`: it is entirely legal for `ptrdiff_t` to have less range than `uintptr_t`.  Imagine, for example, a segmented memory model where you cannot allocate anything larger than a segment, in this case, `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` might be able to represent the size of a segment but not the size of your address space.

### According to Practice

On the computers which you use (modern 32-bit and 64-bit computers), a `uintptr_t` will just contain the pointer address.  Subtract away.  This is implementation-defined but not undefined behavior.

Do not subtract the original pointers without casting unless they point to the same object, or to the address past that object.  Compilers can and will make aliasing assumptions when you use pointer arithmetic.  Not only is your program "technically" wrong, but there is a long history of compilers producing bad code here.

There is a bit of an argument going on right now about what, exactly, it means for a pointer to point to the same object, but this argument was unresolved last time I checked.

Comment: A _very nice_ answer.

Comment: Thank you, this fully answers my question.

Comment: I have tried finding something on the debate you mentioned on the meaning of pointing to the same object, I am interested to learn more about that, is there a post on it or something you could point me to?

Comment: @Kyle: I can't find it right now.  But the core discussion was over situations like `int x[2][2];` and whether `&x[0][0] + 2` is equivalent to `&x[1][0]`.

Comment: It may also be worth nothing that many platforms with 16-bit "int" allowed objects up to 65535 bytes.  Given `char *p1,*p2;` after `p2 = p1+24576+24576;`, the different `p2-p1` would typically yield -16384 (rather than 49152), but adding -16384 to p1 would yield p2.

Comment: This answer doesn’t appear to explain how (or conclude that it’s impossible) to subtract two pointers that both point to the same object. :(

Comment: @Chortos-2: What do you want explained? If you have `p` and `q`, then you subtract them by writing `p - q`.  I don't think that's what you're asking though.

Comment: @DietrichEpp The result is not guaranteed to fit in `ptrdiff_t`, is it? And hence the behaviour of the subtraction is not guaranteed to be defined. Is there a way to avoid UB?

Comment: @Chortos-2: Yes, you get undefined behavior if you allocate an array with more than `PTRDIFF_MAX` elements and then do pointer subtraction.  So the easy and simple way to avoid undefined behavior here is to simply not allocate objects which are that large.  On commonly used systems, it's impossible to allocate such a large object anyway.

Comment: @DietrichEpp That’s cool but, sadly, inapplicable when you’re writing a library function that takes user-allocated pointers as input. Oh well. Strangely, I’ve just discovered that in C++ `ptrdiff_t` is redefined as a type “that can hold the difference of two subscripts in an array object” (§18.2#5), and yet the text about pointer subtraction being undefined if the result doesn’t fit in `ptrdiff_t` is still there.

Comment: @Chortos-2: Wait, you're asking about subtracting pointers to two different objects now?  That's always UB.  As I interpret the C++ standard, the text in §18.2 is really just saying "go look in §5.7".

Comment: @Chortos-2: Of course, it would help if you could explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Oh, no, just a single object. Consider `strlen`. If I’m implementing `strlen`, I’d like to subtract the original pointer from the pointer to the null character and return the difference, but I can’t do that and have my code remain perfectly portable because the subtraction is potentially UB. What actually brought me here is my attempt to fix various bugs in a [locale-independent `strtod`](https://github.com/libass/libass/blob/master@%7B2016-10-30%7D/libass/ass_strtod.c) implementation. It subtracts pointers to get substring lengths, but it seems this is allowed to fail!

Comment: @Chortos-2: If you try to make a program so it will always work correctly on all conforming implementations, you will go insane.  Just assume that no objects are larger than `PTRDIFF_MAX` and you will be happy.  Practically speaking, are you going to run libass on anything other than a modern 32-bit or 64-bit system with flat memory?

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yeah, that’s what I’ll do. (And I’ve just realized that I lied; the code I linked doesn’t actually subtract pointers. It has other problems, and it was just my train of thought that brought me here.)

Comment: @Will: I can understand why you would think that, but I would invite you to take a look at the C standard PDF (draft versions are available online) and search for the word “object”. The word appears literally *hundreds* of times in the C standard. It is defined at the beginning as “region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values”. That is the definition I am using here—a definition straight out of the C standard itself.

Comment: This is generally why I reach for the “add comment” button first, if I disagree with an answer.

Comment: That makes sense. It's just that I had completely forgotten about SO's awful vote-locking [anti-feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked).