# Usage of ptrdiff_t

Tags: c, language-lawyer, ptrdiff-t

I'm implementing iterator through continuous chunk of memory and came to the issue about its conforming usage. My current implementation (assuming I'm iterating through array of `char`s).

```
typedef struct iterator{
    void *next_ptr;
    void *limit; //one past last element pointer
} iterator_t;

void *next(iterator_t *iterator_ptr){
    void *limit = iterator_ptr -> limit;
    void *next_ptr = iterator_ptr -> next_ptr;
    ptrdiff_t diff = limit - next_ptr;
    if(diff <= 0){
        return NULL;
    }
    iterator_ptr -> next_ptr = ((char *) next_ptr) + 1;
    return next_ptr;
}
```

The issue is the Standard claims at `6.5.6(p9)` that:

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object,or  one  past  the  last  element  of  the  array 
>   object

This is true. I assume the area I'm iterating through is an array.

> If  the  result  is  not  representable  in  an  object  of  that 
>   type,  the  behavior  is  undefined.  In other words, if the
>   expressions point to, respectively, the `i`-th and `j`-th elements of
>   an array object, the expression `(P)-(Q)` has the value `i−j` provided
>   the value fits in an object of type `ptrdiff_t`.

The limits of `ptrdiff_t` are defined at `7.20.3(p2)`:

> limits of `ptrdiff_t`
>
> `PTRDIFF_MIN`                       −65535
>
> `PTRDIFF_MAX`                       +65535

There is no any guarantees that all values represented with `size_t` should be represented with `ptrdiff_t`.

So we judging by the limits we can ***conformingly*** subtract pointers of an array only of `65535` elements at most? So this would not work in general case where I want to subtract two pointers to elements of an array of unknown size?

Comment: Where exactly have you seen `PTRDIFF_MIN −65535` and `PTRDIFF_MAX +65535`? These limits are platform dependent, but 65535 seems tiny to me.

Comment: `SIZE_MAX` should agree with `PTRDIFF_MIN/MAX` on the specific implementation to make sense.

Comment: -65535 to +65535 is the _guaranteed minimum range_, actual ranges are of course higher on current systems.

Comment: @Jabberwocky These are in the standard, but it is the *minimal* magnitude required

Comment: @EugeneSh. *`SIZE_MAX` should agree with `PTRDIFF_MIN/MAX`*  Maybe not.  The size of an object is unsigned.  The difference has to be signed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I did not say they have to have same value.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's what I'm asking. As far as I can tell the Standard does not provide any agreement on `ptrdiff_t`/`size_t` limits. The only their minimum value. So the only conforming way is to compare the size to the limit... Right?

Comment: @EugeneSh. They *can't* have the same value if you assume `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` are the same size. Given 32-bit values, there's no way to use `ptrdiff_t` to get the difference between any two pointers referencing a 3 GB array.

Comment: Just a remark. Even if unrelated to the question, pointer arithmetics on `void *` is not allowed per C standard (even if gcc is glad with it). The conformant way is to cast the pointers to `char *`.

Comment: @EugeneSh._It is guaranteed that the difference between two pointers in the same object is fitting into ptrdiff_t_. I would argue about that. The Standard further states that _if the result is not representable in an object of that type, the behavior is undefined._ So I it is not necessary fir, isn't? Or my o interpretation is wrong?

Comment: @SomeName Good point. Now I understand your question, as it looks like I missed it previously.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The only way to go I see now is to convert pointers to convert pointers to `intptr_t` (if any) and substract the values. But the substraction is not guaranteed to have same value as would difference of indices have.

Comment: *The only way to go I see now is to convert pointers to convert pointers to `intptr_t`*  That won't work.  You have to convert to `uintptr_t` or the resulting difference can be incorrect.  Then you run into the same problem of not having enough bits to represent the same magnitude along with a direction for the difference.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Have to agree, yes.

Comment: Unrelated to the main question, but isn't subtraction of two `void*` undefined?  You can't have an array of `void` objects.

Comment: @AShelly Exactly.  _both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible complete object types_. My mistake... Conversion to `char *` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a problem in the C standard itself.

As you noted, [**6.5.6 Additive operators**, paragraph 9](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p9) states, in part:

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` header. **If the result is not representable in an object of that type, the behavior is undefined.** In other words, if the expressions `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, the `i`-th and `j`-th elements of an array object, the expression `(P)-(Q)` has the value `i-j` **provided the value fits in an object of type `ptrdiff_t`**.   ...

There appears to be no guarantee in the C standard that you can represent the difference of two pointers in a `ptrdiff_t`.

Realistically, this would mean that a `ptrdiff_t` has to be larger than a `size_t`.  A `size_t` only has to cover magnitude in a fixed number of bits.  `ptrdiff_t` has to cover both magnitude and direction.  If `sizeof( size_t ) == sizeof( ptrdiff_t )`, then there's no guarantee that the undefined behavior in 6.5.6p9 won't be invoked.

Comment: Actually the UB can be easily invoked. `char *p = (char *) malloc(SIZE_MAX);     ptrdiff_t diff = (p + SIZE_MAX) - p; printf("ptrdiff_t = %td\n", diff);` prints -1 on my machine.

Comment: Note that this is only a problem if the size of the largest object which can be created is larger than `PTRDIFF_MAX-1`, which is not the case on any 64-bit implementation I know of. There are implementations with 32-bit `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` which allow single objects bigger than 2GB, and on those implementations overflow is possible (at least for `char*` pointer subtraction).

Comment: @rici *There are implementations with 32-bit `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` which allow single objects bigger than 2GB, and on those implementations overflow is possible (at least for char* pointer subtraction).*  Those are the exact types of implementations that popped into my head when I understood what the OP was asking.  I'm surprised the question only has 3 upvotes.

Comment: The question comes up from time to time, which might explain that. Here's a couple of examples, maybe dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49380475 https://stackoverflow.com/q/38442017

Answer (score 5):

From the specification (section 7.20.3)

> Its implementation-defined value shall be equal to ***or greater*** in magnitude
>   (absolute value) than the corresponding value given below

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

So the values mentioned are only *minimum* values. The implementation could have larger limits. I would expect `ptrdiff_t` to be the word-length of the target platform (i.e. a 64-bit type of 64-bit systems).

And note that `size_t` is an *unsigned* integer type, while `ptrdiff_t` is a *signed* integer type. That kind of implies that not all values of a `size_t` could be represented by a `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the following example: We `malloc`ed `SIZE_MAX` bytes as `char *bytes = malloc(SIZE_MAX)`. So pointer to the last element would be `bytes + SIZE_MAX`. Isn't `ptrdiff_t diff = (bytes + SIZE_MAX) - bytes` overflow guaranteely?

Comment: @SomeName On a system where `SIZE_MAX > PTRDIFF_MAX` then that would undoubtedly lead to an overflow.

Comment: That was the point I wanted to understand, thanks. Actually this is true for the system I currently use `#define PTRDIFF_MAX 9223372036854775807L` and `#define SIZE_MAX 18446744073709551615UL`.

Comment: It would be cool if you can give an advice of conforming usage of `ptrdiff_t`. `#if` macro would not work with `malloc`ed memory where the size to be allocated is not a constant expression...

Comment: @SomeName Don't use such large arrays? ;) For normal everyday use, these limitations would never be relevant. If the limits are getting close, then arrays are probably not the best data-structure anyway.